# Displaying from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So i am using this code example to get a cascaded drop down menu. But i want to add names of people residing in a city. How do i add that when a city is selected?
link to demo- http://www.infotuts.com/demo/cascaded-drop-down-jquery-php/

Entire code-
INDEX.PHP

```html
<?php
include("connection.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cascaded dropdown with jQuery Ajax and PHP | Easyscript4u.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="body">
    <div class="mhead"><h2>Cascaded dropdown with jQuery Ajax and PHP | Easyscript4u.com</h2></div>
 <div id="dropdowns">
       <div id="center" class="cascade">
          <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_country ORDER BY country_name";
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  ?>
            <label>Country:
            <select name="country" id = "drop1">
              <option value="">Please Select</option>
              <?php while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["country_name"]; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </label>
          </div>

        <div class="cascade" id="state"></div> 

          <div id="city" class="cascade"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select#drop1").change(function(){

 var country_id =  $("select#drop1 option:selected").attr('value'); 
// alert(country_id); 
 $("#state").html( "" );
 $("#city").html( "" );
 if (country_id.length > 0 ) { 
  
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "fetch_state.php",
   data: "country_id="+country_id,
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function () { 
    $('#state').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
   },
   success: function(html) {    
    $("#state").html( html );
   }
  });
 } 
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

STATE.PHP

```html
<?php

include("connection.php");
$country_id = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST["country_id"]));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_state WHERE country_id = ".$country_id ." ORDER BY state_name";
$count = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($con, $sql) );
if ($count > 0 ) {
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<label>State: 
<select name="state" id="drop2">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
 <?php while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["state_name"]; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
</label>
<?php 
 }

?>

<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("select#drop2").change(function(){

 var state_id = $("select#drop2 option:selected").attr('value');
   // alert(state_id);
 if (state_id.length > 0 ) { 
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "fetch_city.php",
   data: "state_id="+state_id,
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function () { 
    $('#city').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
   },
   success: function(html) {    
    $("#city").html( html );
   }
  });
 } else {
  $("#city").html( "" );
 }
});

});
</script>
```

CITY.php

```html
<?php

include("connection.php");
$state_id = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST["state_id"]));
 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_city WHERE state_id = ".$state_id ." ORDER BY city_name";
$count = mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($con, $sql) );
if ($count > 0 ) {
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<label>City: 
<select name="city" name="box">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
 <?php while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["city_name"]; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
</label>
<?php 
 }

?>
```

I think there should be a javascript running which calls on the names of people in a particular city in the database. But i have no idea how to go about. Because i am a total newbie.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a table of names related to tbl_city?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your files should be: fetch_state.php (instead of state.php) and fetch_city.php (instead of city.php).

Basically, you will need to the following:
1. create a new table "tbl_person" in your database with at least two fields: city_id and person_name;

2. create a new file by name "fetch_person.php" by copying your current file "fetch_city.php" and changing:
   city -> person
   state -> city
3. replacing your current "fetch_city.php" by copying your current file "fetch_state.php" and changing:
   drop2 -> drop3
   state -> city
   country -> state